# keypad in iPhone 4 after updating to iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have set my keypad appearance to dark for whole application for all textfields used in app and it works fine, but when my app goes in background and then I tried to open keypad, it is set to white.

This is observed in iPhone 4 after updating to iOS 7, not any other devices.
one more thing if I am opening keypad just in `viewDidLoad()` method, then only it remains to white. If I open it in `viewDidAppear()` or open keypad on taping on text field then works well.

Any view life cycle method affects keypad appearance..?

Comment: ViewController's viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear won't be called when app comes back from background to foreground.

Comment: I am in its parent view and then on opening that view, keypad used in that view remains white.

Comment: after observing this behavior in all retina iPhone devices supporting iOS 7, I concluded that its iOS problem specifically for iPhone 4. I observed keyboard flicking from black to white or reverse with skype appliation too.